# Google Analytics custom variables not showing on reports

Tags: variables, google-analytics

I "inherited" this code that is using Google Analytics to track errors using custom variables but they are not showing up on the Google Analytics website.  Unfortunately the guy who implemented this no longer works here and no one else knows how it works or can even tell me if these custom variables used to work.  I have been reading the documentation and examples on this site and it appears he has it correct.  Here is the code minus the account number:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'ErrorCode', 'BadPassword-05', 3]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

</script>
```

This code is in the  tags before any other javascript.  When I go to the Google Analytics site I can see 18,000 visits and it shows me all of the URL information but when I go to Audience->Custom->Custom Variables it doesn't show anything and says there is "no data for this view".  From what I understand from the documentation and my web searches that this is where the data should be.  Can anyone give me advice on how this works or based on the code if the previous developer even coded it correctly?

Comment: It looks right to me. Check the UA number match the one you're looking at in GA.

Comment: Hi Eduardo, Any luck solving the issue? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This code stores a Custom Variable on the "page" scope ('3' as the last value), and the current GUI, there is no standard report showing page level custom variable reports.

You need to build a Custom Report (table format), with Custom Var value and Page.

This should show you the collected data.

Comment: Thanks for explaining I have to create a custom report.  I went in and created a custom report with Pageviews for the metric and Custom Variable (Key 1) for the dimension.  When I run the report it shows me all the pageviews but at the bottom under Custom Variable (Key 1) it always says "There is no data for this view."  Is there something else I need to change on the custom report to see the data?